# Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown database 'database1'

Tags: mysql, r, amazon-web-services, dplyr

I am trying to connect to MySQL hosted on AWS free tier.

For some reason I am getting an error stating my database is not found. I was wondering what I am doing wrong.

Below is my code along with a picture stating what my database name is on AWS.

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(pool)

host = "database1.creyniq1gyij.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
dbname = "database1"
user = "jordan1"
pass = "mysecurepass"


con <-  dbPool(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
                  username=user,
                  password=pass,
                  host=host,
                  port=3306,
                  dbname="database1"
)


Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown database 'database1'
```

Here is my amazon screen shot of my database
[image]

From @makeshift-programmer answer, I removed dbname in the call and I was able to connect. However, I am not to sure how to create a dbname/schema, so I can start uploading data into the sever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you remove the `dbname` argument and try to connect?
As per the screenshot, it looks like you have named the instance but not created a DB on it.

If the database connection succeeds without `dbname`, you can then proceed to create a DB on that RDS instance.

To create a DB use the following query from `RMySQL` package:

```
dbSendQuery(con,"create database database1")
```

Comment: I removed the dbname and it connected. I updated my question as well.  Would you mind helping me create a dbname so I can start uploading data into it? Thanks

Comment: Thank you! BTW do you have any links/papers that will walk me through using R with MySQL?

Comment: If you already know SQL, I guess the functions ```dbConnect```, ```dbGetQuery```, ```dbSendQuery```, ```dbListTables```, ```dbReadTable``` should suffice. Their documentation in ```RMySQL``` package is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

`database1` is the database instance identifier, not the actual schema/database name. Have you created a schema? If not then u can try to connect to a default schema such as test/mysql.

Comment: Hi Juned, I have not created a schema. How might I go about creating a db name? thank you